# Change probability distribution such that output symbols change minimally

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

I'm not a mathematician, so my explanation will be slow and plodding.

Briefly, I want to create a series of discrete probability distrubution functions, that will generate output symbols in the desired proportions, but where from one PDF to the next the fewest number of symbols change state..

This problem is probably related to consistent hashing.

Now slowly:

Suppose I have a large set of randomly distributed numbers from [0-1) - say a million of them, evenly distributed over the range.

And I pass them through a discrete probability distribution function. For sake of clarity lets give it three output values with the following probabilities:

```
P = 
{
   A = 0.25,
   B = 0.25,
   C = 0.50
}
```

So imagine them on a number line,

```
A 0.00 - 0.25
B 0.25 - 0.50
C 0.50 - 1.00
```

So when I pass my numbers through the PDF, I get a stream of symbols in the desired proportion:

ABCCACBC....

25% of the output will be A, 25% will be B, 50% will be C.

Now say I have the next distribution:

```
P'=
{
   A = 0.50,
   B = 0.25,
   C = 0.25
}
```

I want a process where the next time I generate symbols in the new proportion, but where this is achieved by changing the fewest number of symbols from the last output. So in this case it could be achieved by flipping 25% of C's from the previous run to A's. All the B's from the previous run would stay the same for example:

ABCAACBA...

One way to do it would be to fragment the PDF, adding sub ranges, imagine them on a number line again:

```
A 0.00 - 0.25
B 0.25 - 0.50
C 0.50 - 0.75
A 0.75 - 1.00
```

You can see that doing this given the same set of input numbers from [0-1) I get an output stream with the minimal change.

The question is: is there an algorithm that given a fixed set of input symbols, a current PDF P, generates a new PDF, P' that generates a stream of output symbols that is minimally different from the symbols generated by P?